# Storing responses from JSONP request with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsonp

Thanks for taking the time to read my question!

I am trying to store the response from a JSONP request into a new object which value I can later access after making another request to the same server. The purpose of this is to allow the user to scroll through the data from previous requests.

This is my code:

```
window.onload = getData;
function getData() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=jsonp&jsonp=displayData";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}

function displayData(response) {
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = response.quoteText;
    document.getElementById("cite").innerHTML = response.quoteAuthor;
}
```

I believe that `displayData` object needs to be assigned to a global variable. I have tried different ways to do that and can't seem to make it work. Please help.

Comment: Please include the source in your question.  Links to off-site resources are prone to rot.

Comment: @Tibrogargan I am not sure I understand what you mean by "source." Source url to the api?

Comment: You included it IMO; he probably means source code, which is already there....

Comment: The code you have included in your question does not store anything into a new object (by "object" the assumption is a JavaScript object, not a HTML element).

Comment: Never mind.  Overthinking it.  I guess you just needed to create a global variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.onload = getData;
function getData() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=jsonp&jsonp=displayData";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}

var previousResponses = [];

function displayData(response) {
    previousResponses.push(response);
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = response.quoteText;
    document.getElementById("cite").innerHTML = response.quoteAuthor;
}
```

Now you have an arrary that contains all the previous responses.

Comment: This worked. I can now access the object properties' values via jsonpData[0].quoteText;  Thank you!

Comment: …but the problem is you never know when you get the responses, and the array might still be empty when you're looking.

Answer (score 0):

Use a promise:

```
var data = new Promise(function getData(resolve, reject) {
    window.setData = resolve;
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=jsonp&jsonp=setData";
    script.onerror = reject;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
});
```

You can use it like this:

```
window.onload = function displayData() {
    data.then(function(response) {
        document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = response.quoteText;
        document.getElementById("cite").innerHTML = response.quoteAuthor;
    });
};
```

Just chain a `then` onto `data`, whenever you want - the callback will wait if the data is not yet loaded.